# Can't route using angular-ui-router

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

The app doesn't route to the view. It just shows index.html view it doesn't work seeing any other of the views. It worked fine before changing the router. I also tried to change the ng-view to ui-view in index.html but still nothing happens.

looking in chrome devtools, I can see that both angular and ui-router are being loaded so it must be something in the code. I hope someone with experience can notice it. Big thanks!

My index.html and app.js:

```js
'use strict';

// Declare app level module which depends on views, and components
angular.module('myApp', [
  'ui.router',
  'myApp.jokes',
  'myApp.view1',
  'myApp.view2',
  'myApp.auth',
  'myApp.version'
]).
config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
  $routeProvider.otherwise({redirectTo: '/view1'});
}]);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--[if lt IE 7]>      <html lang="en" ng-app="myApp" class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8 lt-ie7"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7]>         <html lang="en" ng-app="myApp" class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]>         <html lang="en" ng-app="myApp" class="no-js lt-ie9"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 8]><!--> <html lang="en" ng-app="myApp" class="no-js"> <!--<![endif]-->
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <title>My AngularJS App</title>
  <meta name="description" content="">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="bower_components/html5-boilerplate/dist/css/normalize.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="bower_components/html5-boilerplate/dist/css/main.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="app.css">
  <script src="bower_components/html5-boilerplate/dist/js/vendor/modernizr-2.8.3.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <ul class="menu">
    <li><a href="#/view1">view1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#/view2">view2</a></li>
  </ul>

  <!--[if lt IE 7]>
      <p class="browsehappy">You are using an <strong>outdated</strong> browser. Please <a href="http://browsehappy.com/">upgrade your browser</a> to improve your experience.</p>
  <![endif]-->

  <div ng-view></div>

  <div>Angular seed app: v<span app-version></span></div>

  <!-- In production use:
  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/x.x.x/angular.min.js"></script>
  -->
  <script src="bower_components/angular/angular.js"></script>
  <script src="bower_components/angular-ui-router/release/angular-ui-router.js"></script>
  <script src="app.js"></script>
  <script src="view1/view1.js"></script>
  <script src="view2/view2.js"></script>
  <script src="view_auth/auth.js"></script>
  <script src="view_jokes/jokes.js"></script>
  <script src="components/version/version.js"></script>
  <script src="components/version/version-directive.js"></script>
  <script src="components/version/interpolate-filter.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're loading your template and controller in a named view

```
views: {
  'jokesContent': {
    templateUrl: "view_auth/auth.html",
    controller: 'AuthCtrl as auth'
}
```

but you dont define that view.
you have to use: `ui-view="jokesContent"`
or rewrite your router config not to use named views

```
.config(['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider', function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
  $stateProvider
  .state('auth', {
    url: '/auth',
    templateUrl: "view_auth/auth.html",
    controller: 'AuthCtrl as auth'
  })
}])
```

Comment: I tried changing ng-view to <div ui-view="jokesContent"></div> but the routes still dont wory. Do I need to refresh something or clear some cache? I stopped npm and did npm start again.

Comment: look at dev tools, network panel, does the html load?

Comment: Just looked, the html dont load sir, only the js files.

Comment: do you have any more `ui-view` directives in your html files?

Comment: I managed to fix it, it was an syntax error. Silly me for not checking the console, to snowed in working with back ends.. Thanks for all your help!

Answer (score 0):

After seeing your code the first thing I can notice is you are using `ng-view` instead of `ui-view`. Since you are using `ui-router` in your application you need to use `ui-view` not `ng-view`.

So just change it like above and check it once.

Comment: Hi Achu, thanks for your reply. I wrote in my post that I tried this already but the problem remains.. Do you know what else it might be?

Comment: Please clarify the below things:
1. You want to re-direct you page to which route ? 
2. Are you using nested views ? Or else tell me exactly what you are trying to do over here.

Comment: Thanks for trying to help Achu! I'm trying to follow this guide: http://baljeetsingh.in/blog/series-build-an-app-with-laravel5-backend-and-angularjs-frontend-part-2-555/#Creating_New_Routes

And I'm stuck right before "Client Side Auth" part, it doesn't route to the /#/auth or /#/jokes.. Could you take a quick look at the tutorial and see if you find what it might be? thanks a lot!

Comment: Did you tried naming your `ui-view` like `ui-view = jokesContent`.